$M$ is $R$-module of finite length, then $M$ is direct product of $im f^n$ and$ker f^n$.

I showed that $im f^n \cap ker f^n = \{0\}$ for some n, but it seems tricky to find combination of $im f^n$ and $ker f^n$ for $n$.
any hint?

Hint: $x=(x-f^n(y))+f^n(y)$ where $y\in M$ is an element that satisfies $f^n(x)=f^{2n}(y)$. (why does such $y$ exist?)

Because by given hint, $im f^n$ = $im f^{2n}$ so $f^n(x) = f^{2n}(y)$, thank you.
